# NgRx 8 Test provideMockStore - setState for State Slice

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-test

I have a smart component test for my NgRx implementation that looks something like this:

```js
describe( 'Component', () => {
  let store: MockStore<State>;

  beforeEach( async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
        /* ... */
        providers: [
            provideMockStore( { initialState: fromReducer.initialState } )
        ]
    } ).compileComponents();
    store = TestBed.get<Store<State>>( Store );
  } ) );

  it( 'should load items in #ngOnInit', () => {
    store.setState( {
        item: {
          ...fromReducer.initialState,
          entities: { [item.id]: item },
        },
        otherFeature: null,
        otherFeature: null,
        otherFeature: null
    } );
    component.items$.subscribe( items =>
        store.select( ItemStoreSelectors.selectItems ).subscribe( fromStore => expect( items ).toEqual( fromStore ) )
    );
  } );
});
```

I use `provideMockStore` and `setState` to mock my NgRx state. Everything works fine this way, but I really don't like this part of it:

```js
store.setState( {
    item: {
      ...fromReducer.initialState,
      entities: { [item.id]: item },
    },
    otherFeature: null,
    otherFeature: null,
    otherFeature: null
} );
```

I have to add every other feature slice of my state to the `setState` function. Otherwise Typescript will throw Errors.

---

So preferably I don't want to set the root state, but rather a specific feature slice like this:

```js
store.setState( {
  ...fromReducer.initialState,
  entities: { [item.id]: item },
} );
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how to use `provideMockStore` for specific slices of the state [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing).

Comment: `TestBed.get` has been deprecated. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend taking a different approach here. What you should do instead is unit test your selector and component independently.

NgRx 8 allows for [mock selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors). Use that in your component to verify the component's logic is correct.

Then, unit test your selector independently to verify that your selector is working as intended.

This way the tests are independent, not brittle, and truly unit tests.

Edit: The docs I linked are official, but an alternative way to mock your selectors is:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({
          selectors: [
            {
              selector: yourSelectorNameHere,
              value: someMockValueHere
            }
          ]
        })
      ]
    });
```

Comment: I already did independent unit tests for reducer, effects and selectors. This is actually for a smart component. So I don't event need to test the smart component?

Comment: No, you should certainly test the component. However, don't test it by actually allowing the selector to run. Mock it, and test the logic in the component based on the expected behavior you mock.

Comment: alright, same for effects?... because I am using the mock store in my effects tests, too

Comment: Yes, same for effects. If you allow your selectors to actually run, and there's a bug in your selector, the test for your component / effect will fail. It won't fail due to a bug in the code it's trying to test -- it would fail due to the bug in your selector! That's why you should mock it.

Comment: Thank you!... I'll take a look at my code tomorrow to check if I have any other concerns and then check you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As xander mentioned you can use mockSelectors.
The reason why TS is complaining is because how you typed it.

`MockStore<State>` is probably your whole state tree, for just a feature slice, use `MockStore<FeatureState>`

Comment: I've actually tried to set `MockStore<FeatureState>` but it didn't work out either

Comment: I mean TS didn't complain, but there were errors when running the test